# Syntax for an unwind segue in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to use an unwind segue in swift 3.

Here is the "prepareForSegue" method in the view controller I'm trying to have the segue leave, the name of the view controller is "AddAlarmViewController"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //if the save button is the sender
    if saveButton === sender as AnyObject? {

        //and this is just my data i'm trying to pass through the segue

        let alarmTime = stringFromTimePicker()

        let alarmStatus = true

        //alarmmode from segmented control
        var alarmMode: Bool

        switch( modeToggle.selectedSegmentIndex){
        case 0: alarmMode = true
        break;
        case 1: alarmMode = false
        break;
        default: alarmMode = true
        break;
        }


       alarm = Alarm(time: alarmTime, status: alarmStatus, modeIsFlash: alarmMode)

    }
}
```

and this is the "unwind" segue that I'm trying to implement in the view controller I'm trying to have the segue return to.

```
@IBAction func unwindToAlarmList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? AddAlarmViewController, let alarm = sourceViewController.alarm {

        //add code here
    }
}
```

But it doesn't recognize "AddAlarmViewController". It also doesn't look like its recognizing "AddAlarmViewController" as something that can be sending an unwind segue.

What is the correct syntax for the unwind segues?

Comment: This should be correct. Did you CTRL dragged from an element (that should fire the event) to the Exit Icon (on top of the storyboard scene frame)? If so, you should see an offered method, you've implemented, i.e. unwindToAlarmList. If in the (white font on black background) list, click it,and it connects the segue. Actually this reversed segues are created quite differently.